# Why this program works?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, heap-memory

I am a noob trying to improve at pointers in C.
I have declared a ptr to ptr variable strarray, dynamically allocated the memory without even typecasting to (char *) and assigned a string to ptr to ptr variable instead of pointer, but programs gives output "ddddd" how does it works

```
//array of string 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main(){
    char **strarray;
    int arraylengh=10;
    strarray = malloc(sizeof(char *) * arraylengh);
    strarray[4]="ddddd";
    printf("%s ", strarray[4]);

}
```

strarray is a pointer to pointer variable and I am assigning string directly to it strarray[4]="ddddd"; strarray[4] should be assigned to pointer pointing to a string right? and i can see ddddd as the output

Comment: It is undefined behavior (UB). That means it *may* work, but you shouldn't expect it to work properly.

Comment: In C, return value of `malloc` is generally does not require a typecast for assigning to a pointer.

Comment: strarray is an array of *pointers* ; you do not copy anything, you just fill one of the entries with a pointer to a literal string, and then use this pointer in printf

Comment: @Cheatah while I recognize that basically any C program is filled from top to bottom with UB, what specifically is the source of UB in this program? I even compiled and ran it with `fsanitize=undefined` and got nothing.

Comment: `strarray` points to an array of `char*` that was allocated via `malloc`. `strarray[4]` is a pointer within that memory location. You assign a pointer to a string literal to that pointer variable. Afterwards you read that pointe variable and pass it to `printf`. Nothing weird there. Also no UB

Comment: The code is basically `char *p = "ddddd"; printf("%s ", p);` which does the same thing as `printf("%s ", "ddddd");`. So I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: Why **wouldn't** it work? Given `int arraylengh=10;`, `strarray = malloc(sizeof(char *) * arraylengh);` allocates an array of 10 `char *` pointers, and then `strarray[4]="ddddd";` assigns the address of the `"ddddd"` string literal to the fifth pointer in a 10-pointer array.

Comment: The code is perfectly fine. `strarray[4]` is a char-pointer. `"ddddd"` is a string literal which is converted to a pointer to the actual string. So `strarray[4] = "ddddd"` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks got it I did not knew string literal have address too I was confused because we can assigns a string directly to a pointer variable.

Comment: @AndrewHenle how can i get the address of a string literal  printf("%p",strarray); will this work?

Comment: That `printf` will not work. `strarray` points to an array of pointers. You would print the address where the first `char*` is located. Not where it points to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not copying `"ddddd"` to `strarray[4]`, you are copying a pointer to `"ddddd"`.

All strings in C are pointers, including `"ddddd"` (technically [an array which "degrades" to a pointer](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-pointer-array-c/)). `strarray[4]="ddddd"` is not copying `"ddddd"`, it is assigning a pointer.

```
char *str = "ddddd";
strarray[4] = str;
```

Same thing.

We can print them as pointers to see they point to the same thing.

```
printf("%p %p\n", strarray[4], str);
```

Comment: Obligatory nitpick: `"ddddd"` is an array, not pointer. It decays to a pointer.

Comment: More nitpick: `printf("%p %p\n", strarray[4], str);` --> `printf("%p %p\n", (void*)strarray[4], (void*)str);`

Answer (score 3):

I find it easiest to understand these situations with pictures.  By the time your program is finished, it has set up the pointer-to-pointer variable `strarray` so that it looks like this:

```
          +---------+
strarray: |    *    |
          +----|----+
               |
               |
               v
          +---------+
          |  ?????  |
          +---------+
          |  ?????  |
          +---------+
          |  ?????  |
          +---------+
          |  ?????  |
          +---------+        +---+---+---+---+---+----+
          |    *-----------> | d | d | d | d | d | \0 |
          +---------+        +---+---+---+---+---+----+
          |  ?????  |
          +---------+
          |  ?????  |
          +---------+
          |  ?????  |
          +---------+
          |  ?????  |
          +---------+
          |  ?????  |
          +---------+
```

When you called `malloc`, you got an unnamed block of memory suitable for containing 10 pointers.  You assign `strarray` to point to that block of memory, which acts so much like an array it might as well be one.  You set the fifth element of that "array" to point to the string `"ddddd"`.  The other 9 pointers remain indeterminate, indicated here by `?????`.

The string `"ddddd"` is automatically allocated for you by the compiler, and you successfully manipulate a pointer to that string when you say

```
strarray[4] = "ddddd";
```

Answer (score 2):

`strarray = malloc(sizeof(char *) * arraylengh);`

Here you allocate memory for a array of `char *` pointers.

The visualization below shows how this looks in memory:

```
strarray -> ptr1 | ptr2 | ptr3 | ptr4...
```

---

> strarray is a pointer to pointer variable and I am assigning string directly to it strarray[4]="ddddd"; strarray[4] should be assigned to pointer pointing to a string right? and i can see ddddd as the output

Assigning a string to `strarray[4]` is perfectly valid. Since the array is made up of pointers, you are free too assign any pointer from `strarray[0]` to `strarray[9]` with a string.

On the following line:

```
strarray[4]="ddddd
```

You assign one of these pointers with a string. This is essentially the same as assigning a `char *` pointer with a string, for example:

`char *a_string = "ddddd";`

But the only difference is that `strarray[4]` is a part of the array of pointers you allocated.

The reason this works is because the string `"ddddd"` is a pointer in your code.

In C strings are arrays of characters which are NULL terminated. So when we reference the array of characters that makes up the string `"ddddd"`, it will implicitly decay to a pointer to the first element of the array.